# What is the official EOS wallet to manage your coins and tokens?

Tags: wallet

What is the official EOS wallet for managing your funds and tokens?

Answer (score 1):

The original wallet software that was launched with the rest of the `eosio` toolkit is [`keosd`](https://developers.eos.io/keosd/docs/introduction):

> `keosd` (key + eos = keosd) - component that securely stores EOSIO
>   keys in wallets.
>
> The program `keosd`, located in the `eos/build/programs/keosd` folder
>   within the `EOSIO/eos` repository, can be used to store private keys
>   that `cleos` will use to sign transactions sent to the block
>   chain. `keosd` runs on your local machine and stores your private keys
>   locally.

It is otherwise difficult to tell which is the official wallet for EOS, as EOS mainnet was launched by a community who proceeded to create their own wallets, and there isn't an official body to claim any of them as official.